# Is there a way to list the rows and columns in a pandas DataFrame that are empty strings?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a 1650x40 dataframe that is a matrix of people who worked on projects each day. It looks like this:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame([['bob','11/1/19','X','','',''], ['pete','11/1/19','X','','',''], 
                   ['wendy','11/1/19','','','X',''], ['sam','11/1/19','','','',''],
                   ['cara','11/1/19','','','X','']], 
                   columns=['person', 'date', 'project1','project2','project3','project4'])
```

I am trying to sanity check the data by:

1. listing any columns that do not have an X in them (in this case
   'project2' and 'project4')
2. listing any rows that do not have an X in them (in this case
   'sam')

**Desired outcome:**
Something like `df.show_empty(columns)` returns `['project2','project4']` and `df.show_empty(rows)` returns `['sam']`

Obviously the this method would need some way to tell it that the first two columns are not expected to be empty and they should be ignored.

My desired outcome above would return lists of column headings (or row indexes) so that I could go back and check my data and application to find out why there's no entry in the relevant cell (I am guessing there's a good chance that more than one row or column are affected). This seems like it should be trivial but I'm really stuck with figuring this out.

Thanks for any help offered!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For me, it is easier to use `apply` to accomplish this task. The working code is shown below:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame([['bob','11/1/19','X','','',''], ['pete','11/1/19','X','','',''], 
                   ['wendy','11/1/19','','','X',''], ['sam','11/1/19','','','',''],
                   ['cara','11/1/19','','','X','']], 
                   columns=['person', 'date', 'project1','project2','project3','project4'])

import numpy as np
df = df.replace('', np.NaN)

colmns = df.apply(lambda x: x.count()==0, axis=0)
df[colmns.index[colmns]]

df[df.apply(lambda x: x[2:].count()==0, axis=1)]
```

`df = df.replace('', np.NaN)` will replace the `''` with `NaN`, so that we can use `count()` function.

[image]

`colmns = df.apply(lambda x: x.count()==0, axis=0)`: this will find the columns that are all `NaN`.
[image]

`df[df.apply(lambda x: x[2:].count()==0, axis=1)]`: this will ignore the first two columns.
[image]

Comment: This is great, thank you! I didn't think of converting back to NaN, great idea.